# possible to hide 5th element w/css

Tags: css, html, hide

how do I hide the 5th div in a div w/css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this

```
div div:nth-child(4) {
  display:none;
}
```

You can replace the 4 with any number + 1, it just means the (4+1)th div

Comment: mmm that will be the 6th, you need to type 4.